# Creating a Keystore that is valid only for few days

Tags: keystore

I am aware that we can create Private and Public Keystore for a certain peroiod using the -validity parameter. But after the expiry of the Keys we are still able to sign a jar and verify it without exception being thrown.. I want the keys to be not used after 15 days.. How to achieve this.

Please help.

Thanks..